# Conflicto entre nodejs y apache sobre HTPS

Tags: nodejs, apache, https

No estoy pudiendo configurar nodejs con apache en https , imagino el problema esta en el .conf de apache dejo todos los archivos

Cambie la confirmacion de apache ya que al querer utilizar nodejs por cualquier puerto , siempre me aparecia en uso por apache , es por eso que modifique la configuracion proxy

**Error**

```
Proxy Error The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server. The proxy server could not handle the request Reason: DNS lookup failure for: miweb.com:3000
```

archivo de apache miweb.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
       Servername www.miweb.com
       ServerAdmin root@miweb.com
       ServerAlias www.miweb.com
       DocumentRoot /var/www/miweb
       SSLEngine on
       SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/miweb.crt  
       SSLCertificatekeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/miweb.key
       SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/miweb.ca-bundle
       <Directory /var/www/miweb>
            AllowOverride All
            Options -Indexes +FollowSymlinks
            Require all granted
            DirectoryIndex index.html
       </Directory>
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyErrorOverride Off
    ProxyPass        /  http://miweb.com:3001
    ProxyPassReverse /  https://miweb.com/
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto https
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    Servername miweb.com
    Redirect permanent / https://miweb.com
</VirtualHost>
```

archivo server.js

```
var socket   = require('socket.io'),
express  = require('express'),
https    = require('https'),
http     = require('http'),
logger   = require('winston'),
fs       = require('fs');
logger.remove(logger.transports.Console);
logger.add(new logger.transports.Console,{ colorize: true, timestamp:true});
logger.info('SocketIO > listening ahora on port');
var app = express();
var http_server = https.createServer(app).listen(3001);
var https_server = https.createServer({
key: fs.readFileSync('/var/ssl/miweb.key'),
cert: fs.readFileSync('/var/ssl/miweb.crt')
}, app).listen(3000);
function emitNewOrder(http_server){
var io = socket.listen( http_server );
io.sockets.on('connection',function (socket){
    socket.on("new_order",function(data){
        io.emit("new_order",data);
    })
    });
}
emitNewOrder(https_server);
emitNewOrder(http_server);
```

archivo index.php

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
include("../../vendor/autoload.php");
use ElephantIO\Client;
use ElephantIO\Engine\SocketIO\Version1X;
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){    $form_data=array("first_name"=>$_POST["first_name"],"last_name"=>$_POST["last_name"],"email"=>$_POST["email"],"message"=>$_POST["message"]);
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !='off'){
$port_num = 3000;   
} else {
$port_num = 3001;   
}
$version = new Version1X("http://localhost:$port_num");
$client = new Client($version);
$client->initialize();
$client->emit("new_order",$form_data);
$client->close();
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>appp  </title>
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>appp </h1>
<form action="#" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name"/>
    <input type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name"/>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email"/>
    <input type="text" id="message" name="message"/>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
<script>
var socket = io.connect("https://miweb.com:3000");
socket.on("new_order",function (data){
    console.log(data);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

El error es el siguiente:

```
Proxy Error The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server. The proxy server could not handle the request Reason: DNS lookup failure for: miweb.com:3000
```

Mil gracias por la ayuda , o si alguno tiene un ejemplo de nodejs con apache corriendo en https , tambien me seria de muchisima ayuda ,

Comment: Hola, leo. ¿Te da algún error? ¿Tienes el virtualhost en sites-enabled?

Comment: @AdrianFusco sisi esta en sites-enabled , copio el error que me da ahora ( que cambien al confirguracion proxy ) antes directamente rechazaba la conexion

Comment: Proxy Error
The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request

Reason: DNS lookup failure for: miweb.com:3000

Comment: Intenta cambiando http://miweb.com por la IP, parece que es problema de resolución DNS.

Comment: en el .conf de apache?

Comment: Sí, en el ProxyPass y ProxyPassReverse y haz un reload o restart de apache.

Comment: mismo error solo que cambia miweb por la ip

Comment: al proxy pass ponele la ip asi no hace un dns lookup

Comment: @aloMalbarez el eror no cambio es el mismo que el anterior solo cambia a la ip por el dominio ( no use ip antes por las dudas ya que tengo 2 webs en el mismo vps obviamente con la misma ip)

Comment: por las dudas, en el dns miweb.com es un A record apuntando a la IP y www. es un CNAME apuntando a miweb.com? o tienen diferentes ip?

Comment: misma ip y estan bien apuntadas , muestraban el contenido ambas , antes que cambie la configuracion proxy

Comment: Hay alguna otra forma que nodejs funcione sin tocar la configuracion apache?

Comment: Si tienes un certificado en Apache, y tu servidor Node está en el mismo equipo, y usas un proxy server para redirigir las peticiones que se hagan al puerto 3000 hacia tu servidor Node, mi pregunta es, ¿porqué usar un certificado en Node? Apache es el que se encargará de redirigir el tráfico, por lo tanto el certificado de Node sólo será visible por Apache, no por el cliente, no entiendo la necesidad de usar un certificado si Node no recibe directamente la solicitud de un cliente, sino que la solicitud la maneja Apache.

Comment: @MauricioContreras Ahi acabo de probar nodejs sin cerfiicado y el error no cambio , no se que me falta hacer el apache

Comment: cual es la página principal ? la que sirve php o la que sirve nodejs? si nodejs lo usas para un api al que accede el front de php, tendrías que hacer el proxy de miapiennode.miweb.com a ip:puertodenode ( siendo miapiennode. un CNAME ) y dejar el www que lo maneje apache+php

Comment: Si no tienes un CNAME o no deseas configurar uno, puedes usar una ruta de tu Apache para redireccionar las peticiones a dicha ruta hacia tu servidor Node. Por ejemplo: `https://miweb.com/api`. Así lo tengo yo en mi web personal: [Ejemplo de API en con Node en Apache](https://omnipc.ddns.net/api/quotes).

Comment: La pagina principal donde esta el index.php ( de node ) es https://miweb.com/sistema/index.php ( aca es donde sale el error )  y si cambio  ProxyPass  /node(por ejemplo) el error que aparece  es :Mixed Content: The page at '<URL>' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint '<URL>'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: y si cambio a https:miweb.com:3000 para evitar ese error y conectarlo bajo me sale  https , net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: @MauricioContreras Vi que tu api funciona perfecto , pero no entiendo adonde llamar nodejs  use https://miweb.com:3000  y http://miweb.com:3000 y con ninguno logro conectarme

Comment: No coloques solucionado al título de tu pregunta, con marcar una respuesta como aceptada alcanza

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

Tu problema está en la forma en la que configuras tu [Proxy Inverso](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_inverso) en Apache. Actualmente tienes configurada la ruta hacia tu API de la siguiente forma:

```sh
ProxyPass        /  http://miweb.com:3001
ProxyPassReverse /  https://miweb.com/
```

Las líneas anteriores indican que toda solicitud realizada a `miweb.com` serán manejadas por tu servidor `Node` levantado en el puerto 3001.

Ahora bien, la directiva [`ProxyPassReverse`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/es/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse), también debe apuntar al puerto desde el cual se puede estar recibiendo una respuesta a una solicitud, para poder establecer las cabeceras apropiadas y ocultar así la dirección interna desde donde ha sido redirigida la respuesta.

Entonces, cada vez que intentas acceder a algún recurso en `miweb.com`, esa solicitud será reenviada hacia tu servidor Node. Por ejemplo, si deseas acceder a `miweb.com/recurso`, la petición será reenviada a `<servidornode>:3001/recurso`. A menos que tu servidor Node esté específicamente diseñado para manejar todas la solicitudes, esto generará el error que actualmente tienes. Me permití realizar el cambio en mi propio servidor, obteniendo el mismo resultado de error que obtienes actualmente:

[image: Mensaje de Error Proxy Reverse]

**SOLUCIÓN**

Suponiendo que por alguna razón, el puerto 3001 de tu aplicación Node es un puerto público (es decir que se puede acceder desde el exterior, mediante un nombre de host o una dirección IP), entonces no habría necesidad de un Servidor proxy inverso.

Ahora, si lo que quieres es mantener tu Servidor Node detrás de tu servidor Apache, entonces una de la cosas que podrías hacer es crear una ruta específica en tu servidor para redireccionar las peticiones que deben ser manejadas por Node.

Por ejemplo, estableces la siguiente ruta (comúnmente usada):

```
https://miweb.com/api
```

Todas las peticiones a dicha ruta, serán redirigidas a tu servidor Node.

(Nota, no confundir `/api` con la ruta raíz de Node, para node todas la peticiones vendrán como si se tratara de la ruta raíz del servidor Node levantado en el puerto 3001).

Suponiendo que tu servidor Node se encuentra en el mismo equipo en el que ejecutas Apache, la configuración de tu Servidor Apache debería lucir así:

```sh
ProxyPass        /api  http://localhost:3001
ProxyPassReverse /api  http://localhost:3001
```

Si tu servidor Node se encuentra en un equipo diferente al de tu servidor Apache, entonces debes reemplazar `localhost` por la dirección IP de dicho equipo.

Por último no olvides reiniciar Apache para que tome los cambios realizados.

**Solicitudes**

A partir de este momento todas las solicitudes a tu Servidor Node, son realizadas desde Apache mediante el proxy inverso. De cara al público, el `endpoint` para tu servidor Node es `miweb.com/api`. Sin necesidad de colocar el puerto, ya que el servidor Proxy se encargará de redireccionar al puerto adecuado.

Por ejmplo:

```js
//esta línea:
var socket = io.connect("https://miweb.com:3000");
//la debes cambiar por:
var socket = io.connect("https://miweb.com/api");
```

La configuración de PHP se verá afectada de forma similar.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: Mauricio me tome 2 dias en probar todas las formas posibles ( ya que estoy seguro que tu respuesta es correcta ) y la verdad no consigo que funcione , la verdad me resigne , tenes o hay en algun lado , un ejemplo que funcione sobre https ( sin usar proxy ) , mil gracias y disculpas por el abuso de tu tiempo

Comment: A ver, que no entiendo, necesitas usar proxy o no lo necesitas. Por norma general, se evita exponer un servidor Node a Internet, por razones de seguridad. Mi pregunta inicial, ¿cómo pretendes *consumir* tu API? ¿Tienes abierto el puerto 3000 de cara a Internet? Me refiero a que las consultas o solicitudes a `https://miweb.com` las maneja Apache, mientras que las consultas a `https://miweb.com:3000` las maneja Node. De esta forma no necesitas un servidor proxy reverso. Saludos

Comment: Mauricio , te explico lo que necesito , tengo 2 paginas home,html y agregaritem,html , cuando el usuario agrega un item en ( agregaitem.html ) quiero que node actualice home.html ( la tipica notificacion "hay un nuevo item"), por lo que imagino ( no lo se ) las 2 paginas tienen que estar conectadas a node!

Comment: Mauricio funcionaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa mil millones de gracias!!!!